# Default Date a year ago from today using materialize

Tags: jquery, datepicker, materialize

Is a possible using default date a year ago using **the latest** materialize js version?

because the documentation, just showing

> minDate - Date(type) - null (Default) - The earliest date that can be
>   selected. (description)

https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

I try use like this

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  minDate : new Date()- 360
});
```

It didn't work fine.
By the way I still confused that I should use **minDate** or **defaultDate**. Any idea? 
here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/72a5ugyv/2/

thank you

Comment: minDate will set the minimum date that can be selected. Where as default date will set the date chosen if the user hasnt already made the selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minus 1 current year and then pass date to `minDate` :

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var date = new Date(year - 1, month, day);

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  autoClose : true,
  format : 'dd mmm yyyy',
  minDate:  date
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72a5ugyv/36/)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from materialize manual:

> defaultDate -> The initial date to view when first opened.
>
> minDate -> The earliest date that can be selected.

You can use the following to create current date -1 year

```
            var date = new Date();
            this.setDate( date.getFullYear() -1, date.getMonth(), date.getDate() )
```

Comment: yes, I got the point the difference of defaultDate and minDate. I will use minDate for this case. I try using your code but didn't work. Correct me if i wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/72a5ugyv/21/